# Precision-recall curve for two class problem

Tags: precision

I'm wondering how to compute the precision-recall curve for the following problem:

Let's say the true values are [1 0 1 1 1]
Predicted values are [1 1 0 1 1]
We have two values only that were not predicted properly. Can we evaluate (let's say via Matlab) a precision-recall curve for binary-only values?  Assuming the real data are much larger.

Best regards,
Sincerely

Comment: You can, but I'm afraid it won't be a meaningful curve. Because, while drawing PR curve, you change a threshold and make your outputs binary by comparing to that. However, your outputs are already in binary.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem I have.  is there a validation tool to tell how good my threshold is?

Comment: In my question above, I have the true values, then I applied a threshold to detect these values.

Comment: To plot the curve, you use unthresholded values.

Comment: Thank you, for your reposne.